# ES6 import importing undefined

Tags: javascript, import

I have two files in my react app:

```
/* MyApp/components/my-component.jsx */

export class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  // ...
};

console.log(MyComponent); // (1)
```

And

```
/* MyApp/my-app.jsx */

import MyComponent from './components/my-component';

console.log(MyComponent); // (2)
```

`console.log` number `(1)` gives me this: `function MyComponent(props, context) {...`.
But `console.log` number `(2)` gives me `undefined`.

What am I doing wrong? It seems pretty straightforward and yet won't work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look in the documentation:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

The following form of the import statement is only for a module with a default export.

```
import MyComponent from './components/my-component';
```

You need to do this:

```
import {MyComponent} from './components/my-component';
```

Or export your class as the default, then the import will work as you wrote it:

```
export default class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  // ...
};
```